# Why the code below doesn't trigger the dir call in a CMD window?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open a `CMD` window and call dir in it.

```
r = Shell("cmd.exe", vbNormalFocus)
AppActivate r
SendKeys "dir", True 'put your exe path/name here instead of dir
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

It opens `cmd.exe` but doesn't print `dir` in it or execute `dir` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simple call:

```
r = Shell("cmd.exe /k dir", vbNormalFocus)
```

This call will execute the dir command in cmd for you without playing with SendKeys.

Comment: what \k stands for? it works but why my original code didn't ? :)

Comment: That executes a command and will *not* exit after. See also the console output if you enter `cmd /?`. By the way I you like to exit after executing use `/c` instad.